# No output produced when running mypy in a Cygwin term, but expected output produced in DOS (cmd) window (same .py file)

Tags: python, cygwin, mypy

Contents of the file `junk_ano.py`:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    greeting('Bob', 'Eve')
    greeting(3)
    greeting(b'Alice')
```

Output when running in a DOS (cmd) window is what I expected:

```
C:\bjk\tmp>mypy junk_ano.py
junk_ano.py:5: error: Too many arguments for "greeting"
junk_ano.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "greeting" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
junk_ano.py:7: error: Argument 1 to "greeting" has incompatible type "bytes"; expected "str"
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

When I run the same command on the same file in a Cygwin terminal window, there is no output.  (Same lack of results if I use the `-v` or `--strict` flags.)  There **is** a noticeable span of time (~0.5 sec) before the next command prompt appears, so it seems to me like *something* is being run in response to the command.

On a probably related note, running in DOS window causes creation of a directory named `.mypy_cache`.  No such directory is created when running in a Cygwin terminal.

Anyone got any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

P.S. Running on Win10, Python 3.9.6 as downloaded from python.org (for Windows).  Version of mypy: 0.931, obtained via `python -m pip install mypy`.

Comment: for understanding the lack of output from Mintty terminal https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I don't think that's it, because every other .exe file that seems similar behaves properly; e.g., flake8.exe, pytest.exe, not to mention python.exe.